# kendo ui web package only supports html

Tags: kendo-ui

i have recently heard about the kendo ui ..and explore it deeply so that how it is beneficial for me ...what i come know is that they provide some package like

kendo ui for web

kendo ui for mobile

kendo ui dataviz

server side wrapper(for jsp, php, asp)

what's confusing me is that ..i have downloaded the kendo ui web package form the site and now it did'nt whether it will support my code written in jsp or i'll have to rewrite it in html...

please can anyone explain me can i use kendo ui web for developing site in jsp....!!

thanks in advance..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing

Answer (score 1):

Kendo is a javascript framework. But it has server side wrappers for different server side languages. Here is the one for JSP:

http://www.kendoui.com/server-wrappers/jsp.aspx